# How to interpret the logical structure of a US legal statute's sub clauses

Tags: united-states, statutes

I am confused as to how to interpret the logical structure of US Statutes.

The particulars don't interest me but the general question of whether the subsequent paragraph (starting with "in any grant") applies to both (1) & (2) or only to (2)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a citation to the particular statute, it could be a formatting issue with the source.

Answer (score 2):

That's what judges are for. The most likely interpretation is that the structure of the code there would have the unnumbered part apply to both numbered clauses. Which is how is seems to be interpreted. United States v. Cardin, 577 Fed. Appx. 546 (6th Cir.  2014); United States v. Williams, 356 Fed. Appx. 167 (10th Cir. 2009; United States v. Nolan, 223 F.3d 1311 (11th Cir. 2000)

Comment: Hmmm. So you mean this sort of thing in general is ambiguous? It needs judges to decide what the legislation drafters meant? The situation happens so often one would think a convention to clarify the ambiguity at the bill-writing stage would have evolved?

Comment: @curious_cat There are *some* conventions (commonly called "canons"), but none are absolute, and there are often competing canons. It really is up to a court to weigh these canons and determine the meaning of the text. user3344003's answer is in a sense better than mine, because while mine describes the canon I would apply, user3344003's answer shows how courts have *actually* interpreted this.

Comment: You would not believe the twisted logic judges sometime us to reach their desired outcome. The example you gave is likely to be interpreted in one way. However, any opening can and might be used by a judge. Ask Justice Roberts about the Obama care fine not really being a fine but rather a tax instead. Plus, there are many cases where Congress passes nonsensical provisions that leave the door wide open.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/USCODE-2010-title18/pdf/USCODE-2010-title18-partI-chap47-sec1031.pdf), it is formatted more clearly:

[image]

This also matches the formatting [here](http://uscode.house.gov/).

Justice Scalia, in his text on statutory interpretation *[Reading Law: The interpretation of legal texts](http://www.worldcat.org/title/reading-law-the-interpretation-of-legal-texts/oclc/780036606?page=citation)*, described the "scope-of-subparts canon", which states:

> ... material contained in unindented text relates to all the following or preceding indented subparts.

This isn't an absolute canon, since legislative members aren't always voting on the fully formatted text. However, in this case, even ignoring that canon, or even without the more clear formatting, the free-standing section applies to (a) as a whole. This is clear because it establishes the penalty for violating (a) and it is necessary in order to finish the sentence started when reading through (1).

Said another way, if the paragraph in question did *not* apply to (1), reading through (1) would give the following, nonsensical non-sentence:

> Whoever knowingly executes, or attempts to execute, any scheme or artifice with the intent to defraud the United States.

Comment: Wow. So indentation matters!

Comment: The website I was referring to indents it differently: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1031

Comment: @curious_cat I think that's a bug in their formatting code. If you look at what they tried to do in the source "(a) Whoever knowingly..." is in a section that starts `<div class="subsection indent0">`, and the "in any grant" paragraph is in a section that starts `<div class="continuation indent0 firstIndent0">`. So, it looks like they meant to have it display at the same indent level as the (a).

Comment: Wow. That's a neat piece of html detective work there by you.

Comment: @curious_cat Indentation *can* matter, but there are other canons of construction that all work together to help determine the meaning of the text as understood by the drafters. Things like, "don't interpret a section in a way that makes the document ineffective"

Comment: If you were doing this for real, you'd go to the text of the statute that enacted the provision.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is really a too-long elaboration on Dawn's answer, which is correct. The assembled versions that you find published as the US Code are the of applying the instructions given by Congress, so [Pub. L. 111–21, § 2(d)](http://uscode.house.gov/statviewer.htm?volume=123&page=1618) is where the "in any grant, contract, subcontract, subsidy" wording was added. The law itself says:

> Section 1031(a) of title 18, United States Code, is amended by –
>         (1)
>   inserting after “or promises, in” the following: “any grant, contract,
>   subcontract, subsidy, loan, guarantee, insurance, or other form of
>   Federal assistance, including through the Troubled Asset Relief
>   Program, an economic stimulus, recovery or rescue plan provided by the
>   Government, or the Government’s purchase of any troubled asset as
>   defined in the Emergency Economic Stabilization Act of 2008, or in”;

Section 1031(a) is amended, not Section 1031(a)(2). The indentation reflects that the added text applies to both parts of the disjunct "a or b".

A linguistic analysis of the statute also requires a wide-scope interpretation. It is difficult to see this given how verbose statutes are, but by reducing the wording (take out some of the add-on base-covering conditions), you can see what the logical structure of the resulting statute is. E.g. "executes or attempts to execute" can be reduced to "executes", since we can understand separately that the law applies not just to successes but also attempts. The core sentence is:

> Whoever executes any scheme to defraud the United States or to obtain
>   money by false pretenses in any grant shall be fined.

Given the letter subsectioning, the question is how to parse this into a meaningful proposition. If we suppose that "in any grant" applies only to "obtain money by false pretenses" and not to "defraud the United States", then we would be interpreting the law as combining the sentences "Whoever executes any scheme to defraud the United States" and "Whoever executes any scheme to obtain money by false pretenses in any grant shall be fined". The latter is a perfectly sensible and well-formed sentence: but that parsing leaves sub-clause 2 as a meaningless subject with no predicate – it doesn't say what would happen if someone were to defraud the US. Interpreting the "any grant" text as modifying both disjuncts provides a predicate for both subjects, thus is meaningful and grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to 18 U.S.C. § 1031, Major Fraud against the United States, the "in grant" part applies to 1 & 2.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on your reasoning? How could you tell.